# Access VBA Can i print an A4 Report to A3 with "Fit to size"?

Tags: vba, ms-access, printing, report

Im having trouble with some reports.
My boss wants to be able to print a report in both A4 and A3.
I can easily print my report in A4 because all the reports is built to fit an A4 page.
But when i try to change .Papersize to acPRPSA3 the report sure enough comes out on A3 paper, but on the paper, its just the A4 report printed on A3. Hard to explain. But the report is just printed on A3 without beeing zoomed in to fit the entire paper.

Here is my code

```
Public Sub PrintReport()
'This code prints my report to A4
Dim rpt As Report

DoCmd.OpenReport "VrptGrafResultaterSumpLer", View:=acViewPreview, WindowMode:=acHidden

Set rpt = Reports("VrptGrafResultaterSumpLer")
Set rpt.Printer = Application.Printers("SHARP MX-2614N PCL6")

With rpt.Printer
    .PaperBin = 258
    .PaperSize = acPRPSA4
    .Copies = 1
    .Orientation = acPRORLandscape
    .Duplex = acPRDPVertical
    .PrintQuality = acPRPQDraft
End With
Timeout (1)
DoCmd.OpenReport "VrptGrafResultaterSumpLer"
DoCmd.Close acReport, "VrptGrafResultaterSumpLer"
End Sub
```

if i print the report manually i have a setting as shown in the picture.
Can i somehow access that in VBA so i dont have to make new reports for every report he wants to print in 
A3?

[image]

Comment: I don't think such "special" properties of a printer are transferred to the Printer object. But couldn't you programmatically change dimensions of the report and its content before printing?

Comment: Hey braX. thanks for input. I guess i have to do it that way then.
I know that to do this i have to open the report hidden in designview, do my changes, then print and close. 

Its easy to change the report width and height, but how do i change the size of a chart on the report to fill the entire report on print? And how do i do it if its a 'normal' report with textboxes and stuff?

Again, thanks for helping

Comment: Not sure, if _design view_ is needed. As a start, try to adjust the width and height of the chart in the _OnOpen_ event.